# DATE_ADD issue in the mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to show all the data from table which is having `DATE` between **Today** and the **Next Friday**,

For this I ran a query:

```
Select * 
FROM table 
WHERE

  date_row BETWEEN now()+1 
  and DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 
    (9 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=5, 8, DAYOFWEEK(now()))) DAY)
```

The Result set not returning the data of **Next Friday**.

Comment: You tagged this both mysql and sql-server (which is MS SQL Server). I assume it's really just MySQL.  And if you tagged err 1064, what is the exact error message you recieved?

Comment: it is just a sql query improper result set for mysql table.no error msg.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `now()+1`?  Do `SELECT now()+1;`  and see what result it gives you -- it won't be a date...

Comment: i need all row between today and next friday.data is coming but next friday data excluding.this is the issue.some changes require in between now()+1 and DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL (9 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=5, 8, DAYOFWEEK(now()))) DAY)

Comment: Is `date_row` a `DATETIME` field?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL starts days from 1 (Sunday).  Use `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()` to truncate off the time portions so you're only working with dates and call `DATE(date_row)` to truncate it there as well.

If today is Friday, add 7 days. If today is not Friday but before Friday, add (6 - today's weekday).  If today is Saturday, add 6 days.

```
WHERE
  DATE(date_row) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (
      /* It's Friday, add 7 */
      IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=6, 7, 
      /* It's Saturday, add 6 */
      IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=7, 6,
      /* All other days, add 6 - weekday */
      (6 -DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())))))
   DAY )
```

If you mean to say you want Friday of *next week* rather than *the next Friday*, then Friday and Saturday are the same, but the other days are (7 + (6 - today's weekday))

```
WHERE
  DATE(date_row) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (
      /* It's Friday, add 7 */
      IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=6, 7, 
      /* It's Saturday, add 6 */
      IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=7, 6,
      /* All other days, add 6 - weekday + 7*/
      (7 + (6 -DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()))))))
   DAY )
```

And then you can just simplify it down without the `IF()` logic because for Friday 6 + 7 + (6-6) = 7, and for Saturday 7 + 7 + 6 - 7 = 6.

```
WHERE 
  DATE(date_row) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (7 + (6 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()))) DAY)
```

#### Final update:

If you don't want to return today if today is Friday, you can't use `CURDATE()` in the `BETWEEN`. Add an `OR` condition to execute if it is Friday.

```
WHERE
  /* If today is Friday, exclude today, and start counting tomorrow */
  (DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) = 6 
     AND DATE(date_row) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  )  
  OR ( 
    DATE(date_row) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL ( 
      /* It's Saturday, add 6 */
      IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=7, 6,
      /* All other days, add 6 - weekday + 7*/
      (7 + (6 -DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())))))
    DAY )
  )
```

Comment: this will work for all the days condition ? like if today is wednesday      .then it will return the rows for next 2 days only ?

Comment: @mayankbaluni How do you define "Next Friday"? Is it _the next Firday that occurs_, or _one week from this week's Friday_?

Comment: it should follow both the cases.if today is wednesday then query should return this friday and is today is saturday then query should return next week friday result

Comment: @mayankbaluni That's exactly what my first example above does.

Comment: in the query WHERE
  DATE(date_row) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (
      /* It's Friday, add 7 */
      IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=6, 7, 
      /* It's Saturday, add 6 */
      IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=7, 6,
      /* All other days, add 6 - weekday */
      (6 -DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())))))
   DAY ) . if i need to exclude the friday.if today is friday.what will i do ? if today is wednesday then query should return this friday and is today is saturday then query should return next week friday result.but if today is friday,just exclude this day.

Comment: What do you mean exclude the day if today is friday? Do you mean return next Friday, or do nothing, or return NULL???

Comment: tis query working fine for me.except i need one more condition.if today is friday it will return next week friday.                          WHERE
  DATE(date_row) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND
    DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (
      /* It's Friday, add 7 */
      IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=6, 7, 
      /* It's Saturday, add 6 */
      IF(DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())=7, 6,
      /* All other days, add 6 - weekday */
      (6 -DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())))))
   DAY )

Comment: query should not return todays row if today is friday.